# How to connect to an 802.1x wireless network via nmcli

Tags: networking, networkmanager, nmcli

I am able to connect to 802.1 networks via the nm-applet. I do not like doing this as I am running without a nm most of the time and I would hate to load up one just to connect to a wireless network.

When connecting to an 802.1 network I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: (32) Failed to determine AP security information
```

I do not know how to work around this as nmcli does not seem to provide any means of specifying the network type.

Comment: are you getting this error message when you try to create a new connection profile ?

Comment: @Rabin This is a new connection. I was not trying to make a new profile, or understand what context you are using new connection profile in.

I was simply trying to connect to it using nmcli d wifi connect eduroam .....

Comment: I use a script which call nmcli like this, `nmcli con up 'connection-uuid'`, but i must have this connection in my NetworkManager first.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem. If I have not connected to the network before, how do I do it. There are many situations where I cannot start up a user interface. 

I have connected to these type of networks before using wpa-supplicant and configuring the configuration files manually

Comment: Like @tensai said, it might make sense to manually configure using `nmcli con edit` command.

Answer (score 22):

You can create a WPA2 Enterprise connection using an `nmcli` command line like (substitute your own wifi device name for `wlp3s0`, and so forth):

```
nmcli connection add \
 type wifi con-name "MySSID" ifname wlp3s0 ssid "MySSID" -- \
 wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap 802-1x.eap tls 802-1x.identity "USERNAME" \
 802-1x.ca-cert ~/ca.pem 802-1x.client-cert ~/cert.pem \
 802-1x.private-key-password "..." 802-1x.private-key ~/key.pem
```

It will then be listed under `nmcli connection`, and can be brought up using `nmcli connection up MySSID`.

### Authenticating with a username and password

(This section was helpfully added by a contributor editing the post:)

Or if you use a username/password auth (likely via RADIUS) you can use the command below to add it (use the correct `802-1x.eap` option for your network, the example of `ttls` as below doesn't require a certificate to be defined) and then use `--ask` the first time you go to connect to save the password into the connection file.

```
nmcli connection add \
 type wifi con-name "MySSID" ifname wlp3s0 ssid "MySSID" -- \
 wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap 802-1x.eap ttls \
 802-1x.phase2-auth mschapv2 802-1x.identity "USERNAME"
```

If using the username/password option you should add `--ask` after `nmcli` the first time you bring it up to save the password without leaving it in your command history. It will give you an error message saying as much when you attempt to bring it up otherwise. You will probably get prompted about additional wireless settings when using `--ask`, you can type `no` for them unless you need to specify a static IP, in which case answer `yes` for that option and set the correct information, and in the future you shouldn't need to use `--ask` unless your password changes.

### Exploring nmcli on your own

In general, the space of possible `nmcli` settings can be explored by adding the words `asdf.asdf asdf` to the end of the command line to produce an error message stating what words are possible substitutions for the first `asdf`. Choose one, and then you will get an error message listing the possible sub-settings for the second `asdf`. Choose one of those, and you will see the possible settings:

```
$ nmcli connection add ... asdf.asdf asdf
Error: invalid or not allowed setting 'asdf': 'asdf' not among [connection, 802-11-wireless (wifi), 802-11-wireless-security (wifi-sec), 802-1x, ipv4, ipv6].
$ nmcli connection add ... wifi-sec.asdf asdf
Error: invalid property 'asdf': 'asdf' not among [key-mgmt, wep-tx-keyidx, auth-alg, proto, pairwise, group, leap-username, wep-key0, wep-key1, wep-key2, wep-key3, wep-key-flags, wep-key-type, psk, psk-flags, leap-password, leap-password-flags].
$ nmcli connection add ... wifi-sec.proto asdf
Error: failed to modify wifi-sec.proto: 'asdf' not among [wpa, rsn].
```

By iterating through all of the sub-settings, I was able to piece together the successful command line shown above. The one surprise was that the password must precede the private key path — if you put the password later, it has no effect!

Comment: Good stuff, was able to connect after replacing my device found with `nmcli d show | head` and then using `--ask` for the password: `nmcli con up --ask "MySSID"`

Answer (score 6):

**nmcli Wifi**

Get Wifi status

```
nmcli radio wifi
```

Turn wifi on or off

```
nmcli radio wifi <on|off>
```

List available access points(AP) to connect to

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

Refresh previous list

```
nmcli device wifi rescan
```

Create a new connection to an open AP

```
nmcli device wifi connect <SSID|BSSID>
```

Create a new connection to a password protected AP

```
nmcli device wifi connect <SSID|BSSID> password <password>
```

source: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/CLI#Wifi

Comment: I know all these options :( None of them seem applicable for 802.1X networks though. Surely this is accounted for somehow since I can connect via the applet.

Comment: @tensai, I'm having the same issue: "Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: (32) 802-11-wireless-security.psk: property is invalid"

Comment: @tensai, what can you see in the output of `journalctl` ?

Comment: Nothing in this answer has any relevance at all to 802.1X. I'm hard-pressed to see how it's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 6):

`NetworkManager` can generate WPA2 Enterprise profiles with graphical front ends. `nmcli` and `nmtui` do not support this, but may use existing profiles.

[More about connection to WPA2_Enterprise networks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA2_Enterprise)

Comment: `nmcli` does not allow complex passwords containing special characters; however, `nmtui` allows this and much more :) --Thank you @hurst

Answer (score 2):

It seems that nmcli is unable connect to WPA2-enterprise networks. The networks have to either be manually configured or created via the various applets.